# Display local image in react native

Tags: image, react-native

How to display an image from local file?
This code doesn't seem to work.

```
<Image
    source={{
        uri: 'file:///data/data/com/files/image.png',
    }}
/>
```

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct?

Comment: For me, what worked was adding the dimensions. 
source = {{uri:imageuri, width:100, height:100}}

Answer (score 0):

```js
<Image
    source={{
        uri: require('file:///data/data/com/files/image.png'),
    }}
/>
```

For more details visit https://reactnative.dev/docs/images

Comment: I tried it before, it didn't work... return an error cannot resolve the module

Answer (score 0):

#### if the image is in the local system then instead of the following below

```
<Image
    source={{
        uri: 'file:///data/data/com/files/image.png',
    }}
/>
```

try simply

```
<Image
    source={require('file:///data/data/com/files/image.png')}
/>
```

Comment: This returns 'invalid call'

Answer (score 0):

`<Image source={{uri: "file://" + path}}/>`
where **path** is the variable that holds the location to the file